# Is there any QR Encoding Library in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, open-source, qr-code

I have to development an QR Generator in Cocoa. but currently I was used QR Library for iPhone and ported to Cocoa by me. but just found many bugs since iPhone version in Generator Algorithm.

then, Is there any QR Encoding Library in Cocoa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've mostly only seen Objective-C libraries that read various code types. Don't forget, though, that Objective-C is a superset of C ...

http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.en.html

Comment: Now I'm using it, very impressive QR Code Library. But their need more library to output as png

Comment: ...so get image from them, create an NSImage with it, then get its -TIFFRepresentation data, then save THAT...

Comment: Thanks, Now I was integrate the libpng to output as png. and use Core Image to change QR Color or padding.

Comment: Do you have some example code which paint or generate images? You might find https://github.com/digdog/qrencode interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I ported the Psytec C++ encoder to Objective-C. The project is at http://myang-git.github.com/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C. 
The library outputs the encoding result to a data matrix, which can be further rendered to an UIImage. Take a look!

Comment: Not as smooth to integrate as other solutions, but worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I find a validate ios QRCode encoder demo
Cocoachina bbs has a demo could run and reference~~
link:http://www.cocoachina.com/bbs/read.php?tid=15119&page=e&#a

QRCode reader could go to use ZXing,its powerful I think