# How to use C code (libqrencode) in an iOS project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, static-libraries, qr-code

I started coding about a year ago on iOS and have got to grips with writing Objective C and have managed to produce a few apps. I'm attending my first hack day next week and have come up with a quasi-treasure hunt idea that involves QR codes.  I've managed to find ObjC classes to handle decoding a QR code but nothing to encode/generate them in the first place.

I found links to a few objective C frameworks on git hub but all appeared to have outstanding issues.  Then I found this thread on here:

[Is there any QR Encoding Library in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406481/is-there-any-qr-encoding-library-in-cocoa)

That pointed me in the direction of [libqrencode](http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.en.html) a C 'library' that I should be able to get to work in iOS being a superset of C.

Unfortunately have no formal computer science background I haven't got a clue where to start on getting available in my project.  Can anyone explain the basic steps of what I need to do so I can at least Google intelligently.

So far I've read about setting search paths and creating static libraries but no idea if this is even the right route to follow.

Any help appreciated - try and keep it simple my knowledge ends at writing basic VC's.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a blogpost](http://danielbeard.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/qr-code-encoding-on-an-ios-device/) from a guy who created a working XCode project with the library included and sample code. The sample code is the same that @conradev posted as one of the answers. I tested this in Xcode 4.3 and works beautifully.

I tried including the original lib in one of my projects and failed miserably but then I included the ones in this project and it all worked without any tweaking so I'm positive he didn't change any settings in the Xcode project. Just create a new project, drag the qrencode lib files from this project into it, paste @conradev's code and it all works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [Objective C QR Encoder](https://github.com/jverkoey/ObjQREncoder), which is an Apache Licensed QR encoder written in objective C.

Comment: Yeah I've seen that one just a shame about the lack of Japanese support under issues. Not a problem while its just a hack proj I guess... you know of any others?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this libqrencode [xcode project](https://github.com/digdog/qrencode). It only gives you a compiled lib though, no example of usage.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you have to do generally for any C static library:

1. include the library in an XCode project, go to the project then
   select the "build phases" tab, and in there open the "link binary
   with libraries" section - add your compile static libqrencode
   library there.
2. Go to the "Build Settings" tab of the project and search for
   "header", then add the path to the place the library keeps header
   files in "header search paths".

Now you can include the header files in Objective-C files and call directly into the library.

A general Google search starting point would be "add C library to XCode iPhone project".  It's not really a CS skill, CS is more esoteric than search paths...

Comment: Except for the library needs to be compiled for the arm architecture (armv7/armv7s) for it to work on iOS devices.

Comment: You can explicitly define what architectures are required for your app, the default is armv7/armv7s.  But if you set the value of "Architectures" you can say just armv7 (instead of ARCHS_STANDARD_32BIT), and then it will not require the library to support armv7s.

Answer (score 1):

libqrencode is licensed under the LGPL. For your code remain proprietary, it has to link to libqrencode in a manner that allows the user to replace the library with a modified version [(1)](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html). This is impossible to do in the App Store. Your code would have to be licensed under the GPL to use libqrencode, and code licensed under the GPL is not allowed in the App Store [(2)](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/01/09/the-gpl-the-app-store-and-you/). Therefore, you cannot use libqrencode in an App Store application.

That said, here is some code that can be used in an iOS project to interface with libqrencode:

```
#import <libqrencode/qrencode.h>

void freeRawData(void *info, const void *data, size_t size) {
    free((unsigned char *)data);
}

- (UIImage *)quickResponseImageForString:(NSString *)dataString withDimension:(int)imageWidth {

    QRcode *resultCode = QRcode_encodeString([dataString UTF8String], 0, QR_ECLEVEL_L, QR_MODE_8, 1);

    unsigned char *pixels = (*resultCode).data;
    int width = (*resultCode).width;
    int len = width * width;

    if (imageWidth < width)
        imageWidth = width;

    // Set bit-fiddling variables
    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    int bitsPerPixel = 8 * bytesPerPixel;
    int bytesPerLine = bytesPerPixel * imageWidth;
    int rawDataSize = bytesPerLine * imageWidth;

    int pixelPerDot = imageWidth / width;
    int offset = (int)((imageWidth - pixelPerDot * width) / 2);

    // Allocate raw image buffer
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*)malloc(rawDataSize);
    memset(rawData, 0xFF, rawDataSize);

    // Fill raw image buffer with image data from QR code matrix
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char intensity = (pixels[i] & 1) ? 0 : 0xFF;

        int y = i / width;
        int x = i - (y * width);

        int startX = pixelPerDot * x * bytesPerPixel + (bytesPerPixel * offset);
        int startY = pixelPerDot * y + offset;
        int endX = startX + pixelPerDot * bytesPerPixel;
        int endY = startY + pixelPerDot;

        int my;
        for (my = startY; my < endY; my++) {
            int mx;
            for (mx = startX; mx < endX; mx += bytesPerPixel) {
                rawData[bytesPerLine * my + mx    ] = intensity;    //red
                rawData[bytesPerLine * my + mx + 1] = intensity;    //green
                rawData[bytesPerLine * my + mx + 2] = intensity;    //blue
                rawData[bytesPerLine * my + mx + 3] = 255;          //alpha
            }
        }
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, rawData, rawDataSize, (CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback)&freeRawData);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(imageWidth, imageWidth, 8, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerLine, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    UIImage *quickResponseImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    QRcode_free(resultCode);

    return quickResponseImage;
}
```

Comment: I've checked with the author and he confirmed that libqrencode can be used under a bsd-style license. You can ask him for special permission - https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode