# Development for QR code reader for Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, qr-code

I am trying to create a Mac app for QR code decoding for Mac. I am not able to find any libraries which could help me. I found Zbar but its only for iphone and the external usb camera will not be supported.
Has anybody created a QR code encoding and decoding app for Mac and how ?
Please help if there are any libraries for Mac or how can I proceed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any QR Encoding Library in Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406481/is-there-any-qr-encoding-library-in-cocoa)

Comment: Caleb, Thanks for the update.I am looking for decoding libraries and not encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's support for Cocoa in [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), in the [objc](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/objc) directory. The packaging is rough and there's not a lot in the way of examples, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks smparkes.I will definitely look into it

Comment: Smparkes, I had integrated with Cocoa and not able to run code ?

Comment: It takes some moderately advanced skills to integrate at this point. I'm no great shakes at Xcode/Apple packaging; I always brute force things which is not a nice sharable solution. Maybe I can buttonhole some Apple folks at WWDC next week and get through a quick setup with them.

Comment: Thank you very much smparkes.Would really appreciate your help in this regard.Im actually a novice and have just now started Xcode/Cocoa programming.Please do keep me posted.

Comment: Any luck in getting it done, I am really sorry if I am pushing this.Thanks for understanding

Comment: I'll see if I can take a crack at it in the next few days. I spent a couple of hours talking to Apple engineers yesterday so I think I have a pretty good grasp on how to new clean project files. Since this is getting kind of chatty, you might want to follow up on the zxing group: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/.

Comment: Thanks so much. You are a star!

Comment: I actually got this particular link https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC where it is explained clearly on how to include for Objective C but unfortunately not able to get the desired output as I am getting an error.

Comment: That's a brand new port that I have no experience with. It's a port of the Java with bits and pieces from the objc directory. I haven't heard of anyone using it yet. And like I said, better to take this conversation to the zxing group (correct link (or closer; google groups has gone to hell ...): https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/zxing)

Comment: Thanks! I will post my queries here as well

Comment: Thanks smoparkes and others for your support. I have successfully created mac app but haven't included QR code. I have taken the help of 39 barcode.

Comment: Any one Find Mac OS QRcode reader? above library is not reading QRcode just camera only open.Please Help Me.